# How to set a timeout for every selenium test case?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want my test cases to run only for a particular amount of time. Example: execution of every selenium test case should be restricted to 10 mins, it should not run beyond 10 mins... I tried out @Test, timeout=****milliseconds, but it didn't work out as per my example, I could not know where I am going wrong, can any of you kindly help me in sorting out this???? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Selenium. What language and testing framework are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your language/testing environment as Selenium is only an automation framework, not an unit testing framework, so it doesn't have any concept about unit test or anything like that.

If you're using Visual Studio Unit Testing, you can use this to set unit test timeout (sample in C#):

```
[TestMethod(), Timeout(10000)]
public void TestLogin()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If, you are using TestNG or Junit test framework therefore           @Test (Timeout = 10000) timeout syntax will be same for both.

```
     @Test (Timeout = 10000)
     public void testLogin(String username, String password){
     driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("username");
     driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("password");
     driver.findElement(By.cssSelecter("submit")).click();
     }
```